# Is there an efficient way to get data.table to mimic ldply from plyr when there are empty pieces being combined?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a list of files that I want to combine into a single data.table. My basic way of approaching this problem is to do something like this:

```
files <- dir(...) # The list of files to be combined

read.data <- function(loadfile) {
    data.dt <- data.table(read.csv(loadfile));
}

data.dt <- data.table(file = files)[, read.data(file), by = file]
```

The problem with this approach is when you get empty data.tables (resulting from empty files that just contain the header row).

```
Error in `[.data.table`(data.table(file = files), , read.data(file),  :
columns of j don't evaluate to consistent types for each group
```

Is there a way to get data.table to properly join up blank or NULL values seamlessly? That way you could just do something like

```
if(dim(data.dt)[1] == 0) {
    data.dt <- NULL
}
```

And that should fix most of the problems I am having.

**EDIT:** I should point out that I have already implemented this logic using plyr routines. ldply() worked flawlessly, but unfortunately is very slow and memory intensive once you try to pass more than a small number of files.

Comment: This is not a place I would expect the plyr overheads to have much affect. Most of the time will be taken up by `read.csv` and the final merge. How many files are you loading?  How does the speed of `ldply` compare to `llply`? You might also try setting `stringsAsFactors = F` - figuring out factor orders correctly creates a surprisingly large slow down.

Answer (score 2):

That's a new bug in `data.table`. I've raised [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1576&group_id=240&atid=975) so it doesn't get forgotten.

A simpler example is :

```
DT = data.table(a=1:3,b=1:9)
DT
      a b
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 2 2
[3,] 3 3
[4,] 1 4
[5,] 2 5
[6,] 3 6
[7,] 1 7
[8,] 2 8
[9,] 3 9
DT[,if (a==2) NULL else sum(b),by=a]
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , if (a == 2) NULL else sum(b), by = a) : 
  columns of j don't evaluate to consistent types for each group
```

The following error is correct :

```
DT[,if (a==2) 42 else sum(b),by=a]
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , if (a == 2) 42 else sum(b), by = a) : 
  columns of j don't evaluate to consistent types for each group
```

and is corrected using :

```
DT[,if (a==2) 42L else sum(b),by=a]
     a V1
[1,] 1 12
[2,] 2 42
[3,] 3 18
```

but I can't think of a workaround for `NULL` until the bug is fixed.